# Jsf 2.1 PreRender validation on view

Tags: java, jsf-2

I want to have a validator for my password reset. It will look at the URL and parse the token_id out of it. I have the rest of the logic done. I need this validator to be called on page load from my jsf view. However I cannot find a way to invoke the validator using a preRender function. The code below is to call the userBean and check the token. How would I change this to call a validator rather than a managed bean property?

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{userBean.check()}" type="preRenderView"/>
</f:metadata>
```

resetPassword.xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <!-- Preload to assure the token is correct -->
    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/base.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="title">Recover your username</ui:define>
        <ui:define name="metadata">
            <f:metadata>
                <f:viewParam name="tok_id" value="#{userBean.token}" validator="resetValidator" />
            </f:metadata>
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="content">
           You should receive a email shortly with your new password in it.
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

Is there any chance it has to do with me using templates?

base.xhtml

```
<h:body>
   <div id="wrapper">
      <f:view>
        <ui:insert name="metadata"/>
    <!-- Header Begin -->
       <ui:insert name="header">
              <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/header.xhtml" />
       </ui:insert>
           <!-- Header End -->
        <div id="mainBox">
           <div id="main">
                <!-- Content Begin -->
            <ui:insert name="content" >
               <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/content.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
            <!-- Content End -->
            </div>
         </div>
                 <div style="clear: both"></div>
        <!-- Footer Begin -->
        <ui:insert name="footer">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/footer.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
        <!-- Footer End -->
    </f:view>
       </div>
       <h:outputScript library="js" name="base.js" />
 </h:body>
```

content.xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition></ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<f:viewParam>` instead of manually grabbing the request parameter.

```html
<f:viewParam name="token_id" value="#{bean.tokenId}" validator="yourTokenIdValidator" />
```

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for/6377957#6377957)

Comment: Please elaborate "did not work" in developer's perspective instead of in enduser's perspective.

Comment: The validator is not triggered, I have read your article as well. It does not throw any errors. I am writting statements to the console if the validator is triggered currently. I will include my base template

Comment: So, there's no request parameter with name `token_id`? If you'd like to cover that validation case as well, add `required="true"`.

Comment: I had changed it to be tok_id, if I do not have that in the URL it does throw a error with the required set to true. However, there is still no reponse from the validator which I have change to be called "resetValidator"